# When I try to concatenate a value and + 'px' the px doesn't make it

Tags: jquery

I am creating a slider using jQuery and I am having trouble with one section where two vars are multiplied and a 'px' added to the end. The vars are multiplying correctly but the 'px' is not being added to the final result.

Here is the jQuery"

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        // Find all photos
            $('img.marquee_panel_photo').each(function(index){
                var photoWidth = $('.marquee_container').width();
                var photoPosition = index * photoWidth;
                $('.marquee_photos').append('<img class="marquee_photo" style="left: '+photoPosition+'" src="'+$(this).attr('src')+'" alt="'+$(this).attr('alt')+'" width="'+photoWidth+'" height="331" />');
                $('.marquee_photos').css('width', photoPosition+photoWidth);
            });

        // Navigation Links

        $('.marquee_nav a').click(function(){
        $('.marquee_nav a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        var navClicked = $(this).index();
        var marqueeWidth = $('.marquee_container').width();
        var distanceToMove = marqueeWidth * (-1);
        var newPhotoPosition = navClicked * distanceToMove + 'px';

        $(' .marquee_photos').animate({left: newPhotoPosition}, 1000);
        });
    });
```

I get the following error in FireBug:

> Error in parsing value for 'left'. Declaration dropped.
>       left: 666

I have checked several other Stackoverflow postings and the syntax I am using appears to be correct. What am I doing wrong here?

Note: I tried substituting the following value to prove that it works correctly and it does, so there is something with the + 'px' coding:

```
$(' .marquee_photos').animate({left: '-666px'}, 1000);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Briggs, that kills the main image display. Thanks.

Comment: Which jQuery version did you use? 666 or '666px' is the same value so you don't need to add 'px'.

Comment: As an aside, `var distanceToMove = marqueeWidth * (-1);` is the same as `var distanceToMove = - marqueeWidth;` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newPhotoPosition = navClicked * distanceToMove + 'px';
```

should be

```
var newPhotoPosition = (navClicked * distanceToMove) + 'px';
```

Comment: Hi Hamza, I thought that may make the difference as well, but I still get the same results.

Comment: I just tried the code as it was written in my web console and I do not think this is the issue.

Comment: Ahh, you also need to do this:
`var photoPosition = (index * photoWidth) + 'px';`
Otherwise the initial position is 'broken'.

Comment: That or put the 'px' when you're appending the element, since you're using that value as an integer later...

Comment: I tried the above code and now get the following error: Error in parsing value for 'width'. Declaration dropped.
 

0px666

Comment: @fmz: yeah see my second comment... it's because of this: `$('.marquee_photos').css('width', photoPosition+photoWidth);`

Comment: So restore the `var photoPosition = index * photoWidth;` line to the way you have it above, and change the next line to:
`$('.marquee_photos').append('<img class="marquee_photo" style="left: '+photoPosition+'px" src="'+$(this).attr('src')+'" alt="'+$(this).attr('alt')+'" width="'+photoWidth+'" height="331" />');` (note the addition of `px`)

Comment: Hi Hamza, we are getting close. The error is gone now. However, the slide still does not advance.

Comment: Hmmmm, so no errors at all now? I don't know how much more I can help without a jsfiddle or the page hosted somewhere so I can debug it directly.